# How to use spring boot making a common library

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Now I want to develop a common mail service for our systems.
As we design, we want to develop a `RabbitMQ` producer and consumer. On consumer side, we could develop and deploy a `Spring Boot` or `Spring Cloud` application, but on producer side we want to give a common mail client like the interface below and make a jar dependency for other system.

```
interface MailClient {
  ListentableFuture send(Message message);
}
```

But i see spring boot and spring cloud using many declarative method and seems must use a application class, but i just want a class reference and not need deploy. i do not know how to implement it.

Answer (score -9, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/):

> Spring Boot makes it easy to create **stand-alone,** **production-grade**
>   Spring based **Applications** that you can "just run".

But Spring Boot is not the silver bullet which matches all situations. If you want to create a library, you can create a regular spring project which builds a jar and stores it in your company's repository, if you have one.

Comment: The Spring IO documentation addresses this concern exactly and shows how to do it with Spring Boot (see my answer further down)

Answer (score 101):

[Spring Lemon](https://github.com/naturalprogrammer/spring-lemon) would be a good example for this. It uses Spring Boot, and is meant to be included in other Spring Boot applications. This is what we did to create it:

1. Created a Spring Boot application, using the *Spring Boot Starter Wizard* of *STS*.
2. Removed the generated application and test class.
3. Removed `spring-boot-maven-plugin`, i.e. the *build* and the *pluginRepositories* sections in pom.xml. (See how a [pom.xml](https://github.com/naturalprogrammer/spring-lemon/blob/master/spring-lemon-exceptions/pom.xml) would look without these sections).

Comment: @sanjay And where you use Spring Lemon as a dependency, do you add this annotation `@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.naturalprogrammer.spring"})` to the main class where you start the application. In other words, how do u springify all the classes in Spring Lemon so that Spring handles it, if you know what I mean.

Comment: Correct, in https://github.com/naturalprogrammer/lemon-demo I've used `@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackageClasses = {LemonDemoApplication.class, LemonConfig.class})`. (AutoConfiguration could also be tried, I think, but the above works well)

Comment: @Sanjay is it possible to create a shared library that would contain dao implementations? If so, how would it be possible to create test cases in the shared library without a running app?

Comment: @FedericoPiazza, yes possible. For testing, I haven't tried it before, but there should be ways, and need some thought on what might be the best way.

Comment: @Sanjay but this could be fit if we have single app. how do you use same common module in another app ? if we have to do same replica there then how do we maintain changes to each copy ?

Comment: @BhargavPatel why not, it's just a maven library. For example, see the modules of spring lemon: https://github.com/naturalprogrammer/spring-lemon.

Comment: @Sanjay lemon-demo and its replacement project spring-lemon no longer use `scanBasePackageClasses`. How does the application find the Spring components in library jar files?

Comment: Yep @HairOfTheDog, Spring Lemon modules are now auto-configured ( https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-custom-starter-module-autoconfigure ).

Comment: This answer is also right answer, the chosen answer is absolutely misguiding. what a shame!

Comment: Removing spring-boot-maven-plugin was just enough for me from my spring boot library project. Perfect answer

Comment: @Sanjay could we use spring-lemon as dependency in a non-spring regular java project ? if so how do the beans get instantiated

Comment: @user2359997, Spring Lemon has dependencies on spring modules, as youll see in its poms. So, it can't be used in non-spring projects.

Answer (score 75):

The Spring documentation addresses this concern exactly and shows the correct way of implementing a common library with/for Spring boot:

https://spring.io/guides/gs/multi-module/

As the documentation states: **Although the Spring Boot Maven plugin is not being used, you do want to take advantage of Spring Boot dependency management**.

Comment: This is the best Answer!

Comment: Perfect! Worked for me.

Comment: IMHO the key was the 3rd point of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32711287/4458220)

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar need as yours, so far I managed to build a library usable on other projects with following configuration:

`

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>mx.grailscoder</groupId>
<artifactId>library</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>My Custom Library built on Spring Boot</name>
<description>Spring Boot Project library</description>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.4.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <logentries-appender>RELEASE</logentries-appender>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <skip>true</skip>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

`

It's important to mention I skipped the `repackage` task since my library didn't have any main class, then issuing the `mvn install` task does not fail.

Comment: You need to add <id>repackage</id> after execution above <goals> to override it.

Answer (score 0):

I have those projects in my microservice architecture:

--`account` (first microservice)

--`loan` (second microservice)

--`shared` (SpringBoot project)

`account` microservice and `loan` microservice use a common Pojo class in the `shared` project.

How can I configure the `pom.xml` of `account` and `card` microservices to use the `shared` project?

I found a solution to my question:

1- Go to `pom.xml` in `shared` project and add this:

```
           <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <classifier>origin</classifier>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

2- Inside the folder where exists the `pom.xml` in the `shared` project execute this:

```
mvn clean install
```

3- Go inside `shared` folder and Install the jar (change the `file`, `groupId` and the `artifactId`):

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=./target/shared-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-origin.jar -DgroupId=com.anchtun -DartifactId=shared -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar
```

4- Go inside `account` project and add in `pom.xml` this dependency (change the `groupId` and the `artifactId`):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.anchtun</groupId>
    <artifactId>shared</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

5- You can use the `jar` now!

[image]

6- When you try to create the other jar (in `account-service` for example that uses the `shared.jar`) do:

```
mvn initialize
```

then

```
mvn clean install
```