# How to create a library from a Spring Boot project using Gradle

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, gradle, spring-boot

I have an existing Spring Boot project configured with Gradle that contains few `@Configuration` and `@Entity` and a filter. The project itself is standalone so I can start and test that everything works well before to publish a new version. Now, I want to package only some classes and the filer in a library (not the executable) to share this dependency in new projects.

I also want to keep the Gradle dependencies to be available and then automatically load the dependencies in my later projects (boot-starter-web, boot-starter-jpa, boot-starter-security)

I've been searching for a solution but it seems that it's not as easy as it seems. Do you know which is the best way to achieve it?

Comment: @alayor , have you got your solution ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use spring boot making a common library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32696080/how-to-use-spring-boot-making-a-common-library)