# How to add a Spring Boot support to an external library?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection

I have a library I'm developing, and let's say it offers some service `FooService`.

Now, in order to instantiate it you need to pass some arguments to the constructor.

Typically (if `FooService` is in the same project), you are supposed to write `FooServiceConfig` class annotated with `@Configuration` and instantiate using `@Value`ed properties.

How can it be done when you use `FooService` from an external library?

What I'd like to achieve is to be able to instantiate the `FooService` using `@Autowired` (and putting the correct config in `application.properties`)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use spring boot making a common library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32696080/how-to-use-spring-boot-making-a-common-library)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your library is supposed to work within Spring's projects you can [create your own auto-configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.13.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/boot-features-developing-auto-configuration.html).

Once you have everything configured it will work in the same way as any other spring-boot-starter.

Comment: I think that's what I was looking for! Thanks!

Comment: Great! It's pretty straightforward to configure if that works out could you please flag my answer as correct? :)